# Why BroadcastReceiver is not going in else if condition in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to send a Dynamic Broadcast from Services to Activity. When I send Broadcast from Notification.class Service then that Broadcast is received by Activity. But When I try to Send Broadcast From sendData.class Service than that data is not received by the Activity. I don't know what happened. 
This is My Activity Code: -

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            .
            .
            .
            mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();

            mIntentFilter.addAction(mBroadcastStringAction);

           .
           .
           .
           .
           .


        }


        private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// This Broadcast is called by getData.class service and not working :(
                if(intent.getAction().equals(PLAY_MUSIC)){

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast Recieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Not showing Toast message also
                    String action = intent.getStringExtra("play");
                    if(action.equals("true")) {
                        playBtnClick();
                    }
                }

//This Broadcast is Called by Notification.class & Working Properly
                if (intent.getAction().equals(mBroadcastStringAction)) {
                    int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);
                    int duration = intent.getIntExtra("duration", 0);
                    sb.setMax(duration);
                    sb.setProgress(position);
                    setSongDetails();

                }
            } //I have also try else if condition also
        };

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {

            super.onPause();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {

            super.onDestroy();
        }



    }
```

This is my Notification.class to send broadcast

```
 Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                broadcastIntent.setAction(MainPlayer.mBroadcastStringAction);
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("duration", mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("position", mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

This is my getData.class

```
 try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainPlayer.PLAY_MUSIC);
                    intent.putExtra("play","true");
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                    Log.d("EasysPlay","BroadCast Send");
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("EasysPlay",e.toString());
                }
```

I have try so many times. But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `MUSIC_PLAYER` to intent filter in `onCreate` below

```
mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
mIntentFilter.addAction(mBroadcastStringAction);
mIntentFilter.addAction(MUSIC_PLAYER);
```